# Hi, I am working on a program that will return in 3 arguments, a meal price, a tax, a tip and a total amount paid. I am having trouble with the code

Tags: bash, shell-script

This is the shellchecked and updated code. I would be very grateful for any help!
More specifically, the code will either not run, or it will run but it will return an error message, and I will be unable to enter any numbers that will be the price of a meal. The error message that pops up when I attempt to run the code  is: stinput: command not found and then : command not found which repeats twice.
Update: I tried the code the way that user down below suggested so this is the updated code and the error message:

```
    #!/bin/bash
NumberofInputs="$1"
total=$(( $1 * $2))
total=$(("$total" / 100))
total=$(("$total" +  $3 + "$NumberofInputs"))
echo "The price of the meal is: $1"
echo "The tax for the meal is: $2"
echo "The tip for the meal is: $3"
echo "The total amount paid is: $total"
exit 1
```

> UPDATE:
> When I remove the first part of user000001 code, I get this error:
> bash: * : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* ")
> bash: "" / 100: syntax error: operand expected (error token is """ / 100")
> bash: "" +   + : syntax error: operand expected (error token is """ +   + ")
> But when I leave the 1st part of user000001's code in, I get this error message:
> echo I'm sorry, that is incorrect, please enter only 3 parameters.: command not found

UPDATE:
I figured out the answer, it was removing the quotations and spacing all the variables together. Thank you to everyone for your help!

Comment: It is good to [shell check](https://www.shellcheck.net/) your code for obvious things that need fixing, and then update your question with what exactly will not be working. Currently, almost every line needs fixing in order to become valid bash syntax.

Comment: Please add to your question how you're trying to run this code. Please also add the actual error messages you're receiving, so that someone here can explain to you what they mean - and therefore how you should fix them

Comment: What is the code supposed to do? What are `$1stinput`, `$2ndinput` etc? What do you mean it "either not runs, or runs with errors"? Which one is it? What errors do you get?

Comment: The 1st input and 2nd input are the the price of the meal, the tax that I pay for the meal, and the 3rd input is the tip. The error messages are: stinput: command not found and then : command not found repeated twice

Comment: @user445702 Please update the question with that information, and also how you call the script.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the 3 arguments *as arguments* (i.e. entered on the command line after the script name, before you press return to start running the script), or are you expecting the script to read them from the user *after* it starts running? `$1`, `$2`, etc only work with actual arguments. Also, some of those error messages look like you might have DOS/Windows line endings in your script file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)). If it does, that'll need to be fixed.

Comment: Yes I am trying to pass the 3 arguments as arguments so that I will be able to enter 3 numbers, and they will be the price, tax and tip and then the program will return the total price at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do arithmetic in bash you need double parentheses, also the positional arguments are `$1` `$2` etc;

I think you want

```bsh
total=$(($1 * $2))
```

The complete script would be

```bsh
$ cat script.sh 
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# != 3 ]]
then
   echo "Usage: $0 price tax tip" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

tax=$(( $1 * $2 / 100 ))
total=$(( tax + $3 + $1 ))

echo "The price of the meal is:  $1"
echo "The tax for the meal is: $tax"
echo "The tip for the meal is: $3"
echo "The total amount paid is: $total"

$ ./script.sh 10 20 4
The price of the meal is:  10
The tax for the meal is: 2
The tip for the meal is: 4
The total amount paid is: 16
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am getting this error message: * : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* ")
bash: "" / 100: syntax error: operand expected (error token is """ / 100")
bash: "" +   + "stinput": syntax error: operand expected (error token is """ +   + "stinput"")

Comment: @user445702 PLEASE read the comments against your question and [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/623744/edit) to provide the missing information - how _exactly_ you run your code, the error messages, etc. DO NOT write in the comments - they are for us to ask you for clarification

Comment: @user445702: Good point, I added a usage notice

Comment: user000001's code returned a error message of command not found, I posted it above. Maybe there's an issue with my putty?

Comment: It you take the time to format your updates to your question, code as code, etc. you'll make it much easier for people to help you

Comment: Okay thank you for the advice I will try to do that